# Cannot "Save" Modules, Plugins, or Global Configuration in Joomla 3.2.4

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

The "Save" "Save & Close" and "Save & New" buttons do not work in Modules, Plugins, and the Global Configuration. Everything else seems to work. I have gone around the back-end and tested most of it, and it all worked.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,

Comment: Try shift-reload (shift-F5, ctrl-F5 depending on browser, CTRL-R) maybe you have old scripts cached

Comment: When you click the buttons does anything show up in your browsers Javascript console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in Firefox and clicking shift-F5. However, I opened an incognito window then it worked. Then I cleared the cache of firefox and it works again! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off caching in the global config